# Про $_SESSION и error в PHP

Tags: php, сессия

помогите плиз, этот код имеет три условии, первый не работает, а остальные работают. То есть не работает именно та условия, где использую SESSION. Прошу подсказать что делаю неправильно...

```
$full_name = filter_var(trim($_POST['full_name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password_confirm = filter_var(trim($_POST['password_confirm']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90){
    $_SESSION['error']['login'] = "Անթույլատրելի լոգին";
    echo $_SESSION['error']['login'];
    exit();
} else if (mb_strlen($password) < 9 || mb_strlen($password) > 15) {
    echo "Անթույլատրելի գաղտնաբառ";
    exit();
} else if ($password !== $password_confirm){
    echo "Գաղտնաբառերը չեն համընկնում";
    exit();
}

$password = md5($password."dsaffdsa12541");

$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "armpoetry");
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`full_name`, `login`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$full_name', '$login', '$email', '$password')");

$mysql->close();

header('Location: ../../auth.html');
```

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какие ошибки выводятся?

Comment: Просто вместо введенного выражения, выводит вопросительный значок �

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас проблема с кодировкой, если получаете подобные символы. Можете проверить в какой кодировке у Вас находится данный файл?

Comment: Кстати когда пишу латинскими буквами - выводит только первую букву выражения

Comment: а как проверить кодировку файла? В базе данных поставил utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Кодировку файлы, Вы можете узнать при помощи функции `mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents('filename'))` Где `filename` - это название файла.

Comment: Спасибо, узнал UTF-8

Comment: В данной кодировке данные должны выводиться корректно. Правильно я понимаю, что ошибка возникает при выводе данных через `echo`?

Comment: Я тут открыл новый файл и все работает нормально,,,даже не знаю в чем проблема... но все переместил в новую папку и вроде работает...

Comment: Вам спасибо большое за готовность помочь!!!! Заодно узнал как проверить кодировку))

Comment: Видите, Вы и сами справились ) Да не за что.

Comment: Кстати не забудьте про `$mysql->set_charset("utf8")` перед запросом к БД, иначе может возникнуть такая же проблема с БД)

Comment: Использовать `filter_var`, при работе с данными из форм, бредовая затея, для этого есть `filter_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Перед выполнением Ваших условий или же вначале скрипта советую указать `mb_internal_encoding ("UTF-8");`.

В вашем случае, проблема возникает до работы с базой, при проверке строк с помощью функций `mb_strlen ();`, так же заменить `mb_strlen ();` на `iconv_strlen ();`.